# How to make Nunit ignore a folder?

Tags: visual-studio, npm, nunit, bower

Nunit picks up all the tests of the packages from bower and npm. they are all in the wwwroot and it is alittle hard to find my own tests when there is 3000+ tests from external packages.

So i wonder if there is any way to solve this problem, either by excluding the folder in some config or any suggestions.

[image: Test Explorer]